# Is the converse of the first Hilbert-Bernays Derivability Condition true?

Tags: logic, proof-theory, provability

The first Hilbert-Bernays Derivability Condition is (⊢P) → (⊢◻P). What I'd like to know is, is the converse true? That is, is (⊢◻P) → (⊢P) valid?
I know from Löb's Theorem that ⊢(◻P → P) is not valid in general (and when it is, it suffices to prove P), but I'd like to know whether it's also true that (⊢◻P) → (⊢P) isn't valid in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some unclear aspects to the question, so I'll make the following plausible assumptions: (1) You use both "true" and "valid" to mean the same thing, namely "true in the standard model of arithmetic". (2) $\square$ refers to a formalization of provability in the same theory, say $T$, that $\vdash$ refers to. (3) $T$ is a recursively enumerable theory, and its formalization is done straightforwardly (not with any Feferman-style tricks).

Under these assumptions, if $T$ is true (or even just $\Sigma^0_1$-correct), for example, if $T$ is Peano atrithmetic (PA), then $\vdash\square P$ does imply $\vdash P$, simply because "$P$ is provable" is a $\Sigma^0_1$ statement, so if $T$ proves it then it must be true.

On the other hand, if we merely assume that $T$ is consistent, then we might well have $\vdash\square P$ but not $\vdash P$.  For example, let $T$ be PA plus the sentence formalizing "PA is inconsistent". This $T$ is consistent, by the second incompleteness theorem.  But it proves that $\square(0=1)$ (i.e., it proves its own inconsistency) without also proving $0=1$ (i.e., without actually being inconsistent).

Comment: Can you explain or point me to some sources explaining what $\Sigma^0_1$ means?

Comment: @Trismegistos $\Sigma^0_1$ formulas (in the language of first-order arithmetic) are the formulas obtainable from atomic formulas and their negations by the connectives $\land$ and $\lor$, existential quantification $(\exists x)$, and *bounded* universal quantification $(\forall x<y)$.

Comment: I have a question. Let $T$ be PA. If $T \vdash \square P$ implies $T \vdash P$, then by deduction theorem, $T \vdash \square P \rightarrow P$, and thus $T \vdash \lnot P \rightarrow \lnot \square P$. Now if $P := 0 = 1$, then $T \vdash 0 \neq 1 \rightarrow \lnot \square (0 = 1)$, and since $T \vdash 0 \neq 1$, we have $T \vdash \lnot \square (0 = 1)$. Thus, $T$ proves its own consistency. Doesn't this violate Gödel's second incompleteness theorem?

Comment: I just realised an error in my argument. Deduction theorem does not guarantee $T \vdash \square P \rightarrow P$. I'll leave my original comment in case future readers fall into the same logical fallacy as me.